# Отправить шаблон письма методом WordPress

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть шаблон письма /woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php Как его можно использовать, чтобы отправить через php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Естественно, замените емейл получателя.

```
function get_custom_email_html( $order, $heading = false, $mailer ) {

    $template = 'emails/customer-processing-order.php';

    return wc_get_template_html( $template, array(
        'order'         => $order,
        'email_heading' => $heading,
        'sent_to_admin' => false,
        'plain_text'    => false,
        'email'         => $mailer
    ) );

}

// load the mailer class
$mailer = WC()->mailer();

//format the email
$recipient = "someone@somewhere.com";
$subject = __("Hi! Here is a custom notification from us!", 'theme_name');
$content = get_custom_email_html( $order, $subject, $mailer );
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";

//send the email through wordpress
$mailer->send( $recipient, $subject, $content, $headers );
```